# Local dependencies in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I try to deploy my functions, firebase complains about this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const C = require('../both/constants.js');

exports.myFunc = functions.database.ref('aRef').onCreate((event) => {
  // blah blah
}

Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '../both/constants.js'
```

But not this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// This is the invite that goes to organizations.
exports.myFunc = functions.database.ref('aRef').onCreate((event) => {
  const C = require('../both/constants.js');
}
```

Why is that?

**Update**: It would appear this happens because the function will not look for the dependency until runtime. This is of course an issue because the dependencies are still needed. I should mention my project looks like this:

```
both
  constants.js
functions
  index.js
  myFunc.js
```

**Update 2** Now that I'm moving my stack entirely to Firebase functions, I got back to working on this issue again. The module needs to be published for it to work within the function. Just FYI for anyone who happens upon this psot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Putting your functions code anywhere other than the `functions` directory is not supported.  Note then when you deploy it says this:

```
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (34.06 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
```

It is only looking at `functions` and all of its sub-folders.

If I deploy code that requires code outside of `functions`, I also see a "module not found" error in the console.

Comment: I see. I guess I'll just hardcode my constants into functions for now, thank you.

Comment: You can have modules inside your functions directory.  Just not outside.

Comment: I understand. I would like to access constants that I'm using across my app, both client and 'server'.

Comment: You could install your common module into your server module, so that it becomes part of node_modules.  You just need to remember to perform that install process every time it changes.

Comment: Yep, that's probably what I'll end up doing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had modules in a different repository I wanted to include in my firebase functions. My solution was to use a git sparse-checkout to bring in the required folders into the \functions\ folders. I then added a script to my package.json to pull the latest code. [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)

Maybe this helps.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!